# How to enable ASP on a web server?

Tags: iis, asp-classic, installation

It looks like my server has ASP disabled because when trying to view an ASP file its source code is shown in the browser. After doing some research I've heard I can enable ASP on my server using IIS - is this correct? I've set up my website in IIS as far as I could; it's not asked me for FTP details or anything so I don't know how it's going to 'install ASP'... I've enabled ASP via the Control Panel so it appears within IIS, but don't know where to go next. Am I headed in the right direction?, could anyone give me some advice as I'm not sure if I'm barking up the right tree. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: ASP is disabled by default because there is little legitimate use for it these days. It would be an unnecessary security hole to enable it when it isn't being used. Also, which version of IIS?

Comment: I see. I'm using an old ASP based news script from 2003(!) for a new website. The script still works quite well, unfortunately ASP just isn't set up on the domain I need to work with. I'm using Windows 7 and IIS 7.5.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this on my Windows 7 Professional box. Once I added the feature using "Add Windows Features", and refreshed IIS Manager, Classic ASP just showed up in the handler mappings.

Comment: I've got this far - how would I then go about enabling .asp pages on a live web site?

Comment: That's it. I don't see that anything else would be required. Once the handler is enabled, it's enabled.

Comment: ASP shows up in IIS but .asp files on my server still display as source code. This is a given though because IIS has not communicated with my website to install ASP, I can't find anywhere to enter any FTP settings or anything like that, so whilst ASP may be set up locally, I'm not sure how to get ASP set up on my public website?

Comment: I'm confused. What do you mean "communicated with my website"? Isn't IIS running your web site?

Comment: Nope. I have a website set up on its own domain (not running off my computer as a server etc) and ASP pages don't work on it, so I'm trying to somehow 'install' ASP functionality to the website so that it can render ASP pages properly. Is IIS the tool I need to do this?

Comment: No!!! IIS **is** a web server! You have to "install" ASP on the server running your web site. Is this a hosting provider? Then you have to ask the provider how to install ASP (assuming that they support ASP at all - it's ancient).

Comment: I see, yes "installing" ASP on the server running my website is exactly what I'm trying to do, I thought this could be done with IIS (I had never heard of it until yesterday...). Thanks for the info, the domain is currently running cPanel which as far as I know won't support ASP because it's Linux-based, does this mean there is no way I can use ASP pages on it? I thought it was more of a simple case of configuring a few settings somehow, and then being good to go with ASP files...

Comment: ASP is a Microsoft-specific technology. I once heard of a version for some other web server, but it was only a partial implementation. I doubt that it supported all of VBSCRIPT, for instance.

Comment: Sounds like I may be out of luck then? My original plan was to host my ASP pages with a free ASP-supportive web provider, and to then use PHP or HTML includes to make the ASP pages appear on my client's web site - but of course this produces errors. In truth I just need a stable/secure news posting script, I don't know enough PHP to code my own and the 25+ examples I've tried don't quite fulfil my (basic) requirements. The ASP one I have works a charm, it's exactly what I need, it's just a shame I can't get it to render properly on the client's website. Meh, back to square one!

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm sure there are many useful scripts and such written in other obsolete languages that are no longer supported.

Comment: Not a problem, thanks for helping me to realise. It is a shame... I guess I'm back to PHP script hunting, though I might get there faster if I learn how to do it myself. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Enable Parent Path = true in behavior Section of ASP in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Go into your programs > windows features. Find IIS, and go to www services. You should see ASP there. You may have to enable it in IIS as well - you haven't mentioned what version of IIS you're using (or OS), so I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Sorry this was what I was referring to when I said "I've enabled ASP via the Control Panel so it appears within IIS, but don't know where to go next". I'm on Windows 7 with IIS 7.5. ASP shows up in IIS but .asp files on my server still display as source code. This is a given though because IIS has not communicated with my website to install ASP. Any ideas on how I can do this?